# A solution for classpath is read-only in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I am receiving an error when i am trying to set a project from my co-worker into my work space.

He has few jar pointing to his local, when i am trying to edit the build path it say .classpath is read-only.

Is there any solution to over come this?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Well *why* is the `.classpath` file read-only? Is this using some source control which makes things read-only by default? We don't have enough information...

Comment: No its not using any Source control,The project was developed in Myeclipse and i am using eclipse.  I think that might causing to set class path to read only.

Comment: I'd be very surprised - there's no reason it *should* make the .classpath file read-only by default...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change to "Navigator" view. And under your project ,right-click on the classpath file and uncheck the "read-only" option.

BTW, you do know that you need ALL the Jars for your project to compile right?

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same issue. In my case i did following:
1. open .classpath file and copy its all content.
2. Delete .classpath file.
3. copy .classpath file from any of your other project and paste in current project.
4. open .classpath file and paste the content you copied from previous file.
now you can do changes in build path without any error

Answer (score 0):

Infact ,browse to the location where you have the project,change the permission from "read only" recursively to all the sub folders.This would ensure all the files have the write permission.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. This is what I have done since I am not able to find the .classpath file in the navigator.

Go to the navigation mode, 
1.source --> Organize imports

That worked for me, not so sure if this is the correct approach.